# Best way to strip private data from JSon when using jsoncpp

Tags: c++, json, jsoncpp

Problem is simple. Some `JSon` data are exchanged with the server.
Since communication is quite complex I need logs as complex information as possible, to see if:

- server send new value which is omitted by code
- JSon with typo was sent
- ans so on

But at the same time any private data should be shadowed, by dummy data.

So instead see in logs:

```
{
    "secuityToken" : "asdasdgas234fsdfsaD",
    "message" : "user private message"
}
```

something like this should be seen:

```
{
    "secuityToken" : "********",
    "message" : "*******"
}
```

My code is C++ so `jsoncpp` is in use.
Best arproach I can see is:

```
bool ProcessServerMessage(const std::string& message)
{
    Json::Value jsonValue;
    Json::Reader reader;
    if (reader.parse(sMessage, jsonValue, false))
    {
        auto logValue =  ShadowPrivateData(jsonValue, listOfKeysWithPrivateData);
        LOG() << " JSOn recived: " << logValue;
        …
    }
```

Question how `ShadowPrivateData` should look like, to be most generic?

Comment: rather than `container_t<std::string> listOfKeysWithPrivateData` how about `std::function<bool(std::string)> isKeyPrivate` (or template parameter to that effect)

Comment: this is technical detail. List/vector or predicate choice is a simple secondary objective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As to me, a straightforward approach is enough here. Just call `ShadowPrivateData` recursively for all members of `jsonValue`. On each recursion step you should determine if `jsonValue` is array, object or neither of them, and iterate through it properly. Use [`isArray`](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/class_json_1_1_value.html#c8c898f93543e55b67418f94bced20af) and [`isObject`](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/class_json_1_1_value.html#80cffaa0402b80317c0437216bbb6d92) for that.

When iterating through object's or array's field, if the field is not aggregate (object or array), search for it's name in `listOfKeysWithPrivateData`. If field's name is found in the list, determine field's type (using [`isString`](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/class_json_1_1_value.html#06c01d7c1e8151a5844b595ab00f46c7), [`isDouble`](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/class_json_1_1_value.html#0ea567fa51fc808851698bef59b43626), [`isIntegral`](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/class_json_1_1_value.html#ec4f74ef7b776b1d9c8a10fc3bb4add5) and so on) and replace the field with proper value: replace strings with asterisks, numbers with zeros, etc.

Declare `listOfKeysWithPrivateData` as `std::set<std::string>` or something like that to perform logarithmic search instead of linear.

How to iterate through an aggregate object? Use [`getMemberNames`](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/class_json_1_1_value.html#30fa08af88f2d0a038b22ba9f4e88b2a) for objects and [`size`](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/class_json_1_1_value.html#4ca8ee6c48a34ca6c2f131956bab5e05) for arrays. In other words, jsoncpp provides a full collection of methods for json object introspection.

Being properly implemented, this approach should censor all sensitive data in `jsonValue` disregarding it's complexity.

Answer (score 0):

So I went with @Sergey proposal and have something like this:

```
// in header
class CJSONUtils
{
public:
    static Json::Value HidePrivateData(const Json::Value& value,
                                       const std::vector<std::string>& pathSufixes);

private:
    static void ShadowPrivateData(Json::Value& value,
                                  const std::vector<std::string>& pathSufixes,
                                  const std::string& sPath);

    static bool IsPrivatePath(const std::string& sPath,
                              const std::vector<std::string>& pathSufixes);

    static std::string MaskPrivateText(const std::string& sPrivateText);
};

// in cpp
#include "JSONUtils.h"
#include "StringUtils.h"
#include <algorithm>
#include <json/json.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace Json;

Value CJSONUtils::HidePrivateData(const Value& value,
                                  const vector<string>& pathSufixes)
{
    Value result { value };
    ShadowPrivateData(result, pathSufixes, {});
    return result;
}

void CJSONUtils::ShadowPrivateData(Value& value,
                                   const vector<string>& pathSufixes,
                                   const string& sPath)
{
    switch (value.type())
    {
        case nullValue:
        case intValue:
        case uintValue:
        case realValue:
        case booleanValue:
            break;

        case stringValue:
            if (IsPrivatePath(sPath, pathSufixes))
            {
                value = Value { MaskPrivateText(value.asString()) };
            }
            break;

        case arrayValue:
            for (auto& arrayValue : value)
            {
                ShadowPrivateData(arrayValue, pathSufixes, sPath + "[]");
            }
            break;

        case objectValue:
            for (auto it = value.begin(); it != value.end(); ++it)
            {
                ShadowPrivateData(*it, pathSufixes, sPath + "." + it.key().asString());
            }
            break;
    }
}

bool CJSONUtils::IsPrivatePath(const string& sPath,
                               const vector<string>& pathSufixes)
{
    return std::any_of(pathSufixes.begin(),
                       pathSufixes.end(),
                       [&](const string& sSufix)
                       {
                           return EndsWith(sPath, sSufix);
                       });
}

std::string CJSONUtils::MaskPrivateText(const std::string& sPrivateText)
{
    if (sPrivateText.length() < 15)
    {
        return std::string(sPrivateText.length(), '*');
    }
    ostringstream result;
    result << "< *" << sPrivateText.length() << " characters * >";
    return result.str();
}
```

Now since `Json::Value` overloads stream operator this can be used like this:

```
LOG() << " JSON received: " << CJSONUtils::HidePrivateData(jsonRoot, listOfPrivateItemsPaths);
```

I've wrote tests for it (gtest) and it works like charm.